# No SMTP settings button in AWS ses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

[image]

I am new to AWS and I am trying to configure SMTP but there is no SMTP settings menu in my AWS SES console. My IAM user is an admin user. I have gone through all the sub menus but still cannot find SMTP settings.

Comment: You need to go to `Account Dashboard`. There you will find it

Comment: Thanks, @Riz  it was looking for it all day and I did not know Smtp was moved to the dashboard.

Comment: @Riz even in the "Account Dashboard" section I cannot see the "SMTP Settings" What can be the reason

Comment: Hi @JeewanSL, there is a similar question in repost.aws. You can have a look. https://repost.aws/questions/QUUqEKuSOfQQmgnNaico0OSQ/aws-ses-smtp-settings-not-found. I myself have never come acrross such issue.